# Struts 2 keep list values

Tags: list, struts2

Using struts2 how can I keep list values just after click in a jsp button, going through the action and returning to jsp again? Doing this click several times again.
I've been watching that to keep a value from a variable that isn't a list I just need to declare it in the action with it's getter and setter, and put a hidden field or textfield in the jsp, but regarding lists don't worked like that.

Comment: Guess a session would be the right approach post the jsp code and I will edit it to get you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that we need a getter and setters for the respected property in our action class to send and receive date from Action class to JSP and in reverse order.

But since for collection, its not possible to store it in a single field, so you have few options here.

If List is a simple List of String you can create a comma separated string and can use that to go from action to JSP and in reverse order (easy to convert that to list), i will not recommend this approach.

Second option i am thinking to set the list in session and you can always retrieve the list in your action class at any time as per your choice.